# Implement a Windows-like (async) search on an Express/Mongo architecture

Tags: mongodb, express, search

I want to implement a Windows-Explorer-like search system on my Express/Mongo architecture.

Explanation: When I hit **Search**, I want to update the results view (Angular) **on** every match found, without waiting the whole query to terminate.

Is that possible? If so, can you please give an example.

Bellow here is how I implemented a synchronous search, using [db.collection.aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

```
db.movies.aggregate([...], options);
```

Comment: Definitely possible, at least with vanilla js. Reduce batchSize to 1 and iterate over cursor. Any particular problem with mongo, express, or angular?

Comment: Well, how would you code it then?

Comment: Please see my edits. ✌

Comment: By pressing keys on the keyboard. Jokes apart, if you are asking about complete working stack it's way to broad. With vanilla js I'd open a websocket to feed data to the browser as soon as next() promise of the cursor is resolved. Mongoose and Angular will likely add up some complexity to that on both client and server sides. You will have more chances to get answers if you ask about exact problems when you try to implement it.

Comment: ah, aggregation is another matter. Some stages are "blocking" means execution is stopped until previous stage is finished. E.g. `$group`, `$sort`, etc. If you have any of these in the pipeline, you wont win much with async cursor iteration. It will take most of the time to return the first batch, and will return the rest almost immediately.